# 3D Hide & Seek Word Puzzle

Tags: code-golf, random, 3d, word-search

## Challenge

Create a 3D word puzzle where the cube's dimensions match the length of the input word. The uppercase word (A-Z) must be validly placed within the cube in one of the fixed orientations: horizontally, vertically, or diagonally. The program should randomly place the hidden word and fill the rest of the cube with random letters.

**Input**

```
WORD
```

**Output**

```
Display the cube (n x n x n) layer by layer, where n is the WORD's length.
```

## Examples

**UP**

[image: UP]

**AND**

[image: AND]

**DOWN**

[image: DOWN]

**APPLE**

[image: APPLE]

**ORANGE**

[image: ORANGE]

**CODEGOLF** (Can you find it?)

```
N Y R Z O F K G   Y G B V E T P M   O J F K Y O O K   O Z N Q F A R P   M X E T N O I Y   F H C U O F Z A   G V A V O O F B   B V K U O V L F    
W Y L W U H H K   Z M Z X D R K Q   G D D A B I D F   P Y G U I D L I   J Y D O M D Q W   F H B Q Q N B B   T A C F J Q L K   H R Y R Y B Z Q    
L F C D Z B Z W   L E A J O F F J   Z O X Q G A R C   W N N W Y Z S U   S G E V T A C F   K F E O R O N V   K D G Z N W O P   L I W W J L C U    
K L Z Q M A G C   M R Q E F M O I   O K T K T U A U   S E X A Y K C D   N J D V G E S G   X O F P T S F I   H Z B X E X U T   X R Q G V P Q O    
B H F C J P Y A   P I Z G R X N A   A W Z H A Z H V   Q X T E T B Z A   Q A V I Z H G D   E H N J L G G W   V K A O Q U S G   N K M M X R G Z    
B Q K R Y O R I   O J C Q K C P F   F U D R M U J G   E K B F A A C I   K G P O B M N E   M P M B K X X T   V B V N Z O R P   K N Q N J B M D    
M L R C O U C F   A O H U H R E P   M L E T B F R Y   W J S U C Y A N   M X S W E C C X   C U F U V Q U H   J C Z W Y E J S   Z D C U I R F Z    
C H D I M M C W   F W G N I I Z U   C X W Q M C O N   Y O W K X E Z J   U G Y U W Q V V   C N B T A T E Z   W C X Z E O W Z   N S C J P V X X
```

[image: 3_D]

Comment: Nice challenge! Instead of displaying, are we allowed to output a list of lists of lists of strings? Also, does "random" here mean "all possible n×n×n cubes should be generated with the same probability" or "all possible n×n×n cubes should have a nonzero probability of being generated" ([more info](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/91472))? Also, when filling the cube with random letters, must we check if any of the added letters also form a valid solution?

Comment: As far as random, each cubelet should apply a random function to choose an A-Z letter. For example, python has this code: `random.choice('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')`.

Comment: Can we choose the location, orientation and rotation to always put a word (for example, always put a word on the first layer, vertically, not reversed)? Or it must be randomly selected too?

Comment: Also, if we are putting a word horizontally/vertically, can we choose the row/column to always put that word (for example, always put a word on the third row if horizontally, second column if vertically)? Or it must be randomly selected too?

Comment: Random word placement seems more interesting as long as it's placed correctly within the cube, either horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

Comment: I really want to see the opposite challenge of this by finding the word.

Comment: CODEGOLF is found on [`007++-`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269764/3d-hide-seek-word-puzzle-seeker-edition).

Comment: I assumed that the output doesn't need to guarantee that the word appears only once

Comment: Correct. No need to check if the word occurs multiple times.

Comment: Must we include diagonal across both 2 and 3 dimensions?

Comment: Any 2D or 3D diagonals are valid paths for a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>226</s> <s>213</s> <s>227</s> <s>222</s> 219 bytes

```python
from random import*
def f(w):
 W=len(w);G=eval('[[[chr(randint(65,90))'+f"for _ in' '*{W}]"*3);l,a,b=map(randrange,(W,W,15))
 for n in range(W):G[[n,l][b&2>0]][[a,n][b!=4]][[a,n,n,W-n-1][b//4]]=w[::b%2or-1][n]
 return G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBToQwEIbvPMW4ibbF4sKuayKbejLhaLKXHprGgBS3BAqpKDHGZ8eWZePBi9M0/f9pvplO@8/h2JntNFW2a8HmpnSHbvvODmFQqgoqPJI0AM4aZZzcZ0x95A1GQoiXo8We0GbAdzt6HxOCrqtV1Vl4Bm0QoPCLf8tVuCX7hua0YG3ez4Tbr4piTjlNdoQE4BnjGJhvMCdpJoShjRTF1eYhllKInBrnLtjtYtzikYkSl1yvXZKNIk2Ly01nfc7IAKwa3q2BbHpTqsQJCc4vW7oksZ/MxQgMEH86PKLZHpz1Y8/GM/qXOf3CwvnorR8feYlu6k4bpxdxELUUWpK5Rv2nBjk1WApE/wxEph8)

- *-13 bytes* by replacing `randint` with `randrange`
- *+14 bytes* by implementing the reverse of a word
- *-5 bytes* by creating a `b` variable to store `d`, `o` and `i`, and by using `eval`
- *-3 bytes* by removing the `randrange` alias, and inlining the `r` variable

A function that receives a word \$w\$ and returns a 3x3x3 matrix composed of lists.

To see where the word is, change `chr(65+g(26))` to `chr(97+g(26))`.

---

**How does it work?**

The `g`enerator stores an instance of the [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) function.

The `r`ange stores the numbers from 0 to until the length of the `w`ord, exclusive.

We initialize the `G`rid to random uppercase letters (`chr(65+g(26))`).

We initialize three variables with random values:

- `l`ayer: define the index of the layer the word will be written (UP: layer 1, APPLE: layer 2); this variable is ignored if the word is spread across layers
- `a`xis: define the index of the axis the word will be written (AND: axis 1, DOWN: axis 0, APPLE: axis 0); this variable is ignored if the word is set diagonally
- `b` a 4-bits integer, where

  - if the first bit is 0, the word will be put right-to-left (in reverse); otherwise, left-to-right
  - if the second bit is 0, the word will spread across layers (see AND, DOWN and ORANGE test cases); otherwise, it will be contained in a single layer (see UP and APPLE test cases)
  - if the third and fourth bits are `00`, the word will be set horizontally (AND and DOWN test cases); if `01`, the word will be set vertically (APPLE test case); if `10`, the word will be set diagonally-forward (UP and ORANGE test cases); if `11`, the word will be set diagonally-backward (see CODEGOLF test case).

Then, for each character of the `w`ord, we update the `G`rid doing some arithmetic based on `l`, `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 56 bytes

```
Ｗ⁼⌊υ⌈υ«≔⁻Ｅ³‽⁺²Ｌθ²υ≔ＥθＥυ⎇‹μ⁰⎇⊕μ⁻⊖Ｌθλλμυ»ＥθＥθ⭆θ§⁺θ‽α⌕υ⟦κμξ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9La8MwDD6vv0JHGTwY3bGnQjcotKy0gx1GDyYxiZmtNn50KWW/3ZPTsMwgLH3oe6hqla9Oyub83RqrAV@6pGzArSHjksMkJGxVP/ZCwG32sAzBNFRWEi@qMz5L2CuqTw53lqG5hI2mJrbYMYMF5lxJLCYmc7qie8Yk4V17Uv6KGx0COglPYsLWVHntNEVdoytRBs@VntDJSYIdyw2uxfFntvOG4n9H/g6RwWYclnFNte7v0bu/S1SReDVUl4ifXywqoT@K4S1y/njbr/Ljxf4C) Link is to verbose version of code. Enter the word in lower case if you want to make it obvious where it ended up. Explanation:

```
Ｗ⁼⌊υ⌈υ«
```

Repeat until a suitable word placement is found.

```
≔⁻Ｅ³‽⁺²Ｌθ²υ
```

For each axis, either select a fixed index from `0` to the length of the word, or `-1` to spread the word in the forward direction along that axis, or `-2` to spread it in the reverse direction (so for example `-2, -2, -2` would result in the word written in reverse along the main diagonal).

```
≔ＥθＥυ⎇‹μ⁰⎇⊕μ⁻⊖Ｌθλλμυ
```

Use the randomly selected indices to generate a list of coordinates of each letter of the word.

```
»ＥθＥθ⭆θ§⁺θ‽α⌕υ⟦κμξ
```

Output the cube, but selecting the letter from the word instead of a random letter if the current coordinates are from the selected list.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/), 239 bytes

```javascript
f=(w,W=[...w],r=n=>n*Math.random()|0,d=[0,1,2].map(_=>r(3)-1),o=d.map(x=>[r(L=w.length),L-1][-x]|0),p=[],g=n=>n--?W.map((_,i)=>g(n,p[n]=i)):W.find((_,j)=>!o.some((x,k)=>x+j*d[k]-p[k]))||String.fromCharCode(65+r(26)))=>/1/.test(d)?g(3):f(w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9Nb4JAEIbv/IrtyZ26rGJTD5rFGLVeqJg2jQdKDHEBV2WXLLRiSn87RRoTo5eZd5753gXfQbbRIs1NqXhYVRHDR7JiHqX06BPNJLPl42uQb6kOJFcJhrJLOPO6xCI9nyZBitfM1vgJTAuIYrxBBbM9jR12pIdQxvkWiGNavmcWftkFkjLPJ3Ez2jRHq6YDr4kAZsdYktSTPhMAgxWNhOTn1K5OPSiaqSTEuCD7Oizau0fu7X0zrQ1AWb7nWsiYRlolk22gJ/U7uP/c1rjXB6gbOlaH5mGWYw6juL53EOEjVEb0JTe5UBJxkaWH4IRjLTigHwOhjZKZOoT0oOKG/r@GmI2KRp7O8kR3SkjcQi2Ai0RXwadsAWqjxg@NX8O47Ilwa1yXDa/Bx/KWjBfTWzR1V4u7suXSmd1C9228mN/RiTudzV3n5cyrPw)

Creates a 3D array.

It works by choosing a random 3D direction vector \$d\$, where each axis is -1, 0, or 1. (If it gets all 0s try again.) Based on the direction, it chooses a random origin point \$o\$, for each axis \$n\$:

$$
o_n = 
\begin{cases}
L-1 &\text{if }d_n = -1\\
R(0,L) &\text{if }d_n = 0\\
0 &\text{if }d_n = 1\\
\end{cases}
$$

Where \$L\$ is the length of the input word, and \$R(a,b)\$ is a random integer in \$[a, b)\$.

It doesn't guarantee that the word appears only once.

#### Ungolfed:

```javascript
f = (w, // the input word
     W = [...w], // split word into array - this'll be handy later
     r = n => n * Math.random() | 0, // a handy random function
     d = [0,1,2].map(_ => r(3) - 1), // pick a random direction
     o = d.map(x => [r(L=w.length), L-1][-x]|0), // pick a random valid starting point
     p = [], // place to store current point
     g = n => // a recursive function to create the grid - taking n = dimension
       n-- // reduce the dimension and check if zero
         ? W.map((_, i) => g(n, p[n] = i)) // if >0 go deeper, recording in p
         : W.find((_, j)=> !o.some((x, k) => x + j*d[k] - p[k])) // if in word, use its letter
               || String.fromCharCode(65 + r(26)) // else a random letter
) => d.some(x => x) // check if direction is valid (not [0,0,0])
  ? g(2) // valid - create the grid
  : f(w) // invalid - try again :(
```

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), <del>655</del> <del>542</del> <del>446</del> 437 bytes

*-105 bytes, thanks to @ceilingcat*

To disable the word hint, change `w[i]|32` to `w[i]|0`.

```
#define r rand()
f(w,s)char*w;{char*u=calloc(s*s,s);int x,y,z,a,b,c,p,i=s/2,l,m,n;if(r%2)for(;i--;)w[i]^=w[s+~i]^=w[i]^=w[s+~i];do for(x=r%s,y=r%s,z=r%s,a=r%3-1,b=r%3-1,c=r%3-1,p=a|b|c,i=0;i<s&&p;p*=l>=0&m>=0&n>=0&l<s&m<s&n<s)l=x+i*a,m=y+i*b,n=z+i++*c;while(!p);for(i=s;i--;)u[((x+i*a)*s+y+i*b)*s+z+i*c]=w[i]|32;for(;y=++i<s*s*s;)u[i]=u[i]?:65+r%26;for(;y<s;y+=puts(""))for(z=0;z<s;z+=printf(" "))for(x=0;x<s;)putchar(u[x++*s*s+y*s+z]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVJda@MwEHzPr/D5aJAshaYJl4fbqEe59PJSklAofTA@cBS7FdiKsRz8kaR/PV3JKdTGs6sdDRrtWo7epLxcfu6SVOnEK70y1jtCBympuaHyPS6DGo4uHoSMs2wviQkMcqB05TW85R2P@ZZLXnAlzO2EZzznGlRKypsJTfclATUaAa1DFf0XdWjYR598W8Ju79mdjShvDG8ddg5jxOnojm@vUV5jIeLT9iTxyDGouRkOCygCkd2L8TC3oC1kSOT46bmhmWiYCmKeixbjlmvRMcVYIKF@V1lCfhQUrAW8Q@/3EBLiJDQwzGlsgqJARs79aTpxCmgFY@ghwNfKVCQs/Pk9@8WwBbPrprmBloniUBni@9Q1pkPzHdY7rJfYzpT43pVqkGqQoiiw3SeHsEG3xnqxNiIK54uCPFaaGHocePgYN7tK5QkZUwqu1k8wjMTRf9n43H9YLRAX69eVXWw2T48Y188Pq6VN/q4Xj8v10z//3Kv76c2N6pJ96tW3X0k4jkB9u8zRCFOVWaKJbQwFe6pX4WzvIkgJUrJoScUdaX@d8@B8@QQ)

Comment: [378 bytes](https://tio.run/##NVHbbptAEH33V1AqV3uz4kubh6xXUVSneYlsq1LUB8oDXkO6yKwRAzL4kl93ZxcHpDMDO2fmnFk9etf6ev26TTNj06AKqsRuCR00Fsy7TbdBKzpxFInYCC1KkYtCsEZm5CCA6n9JxQ7yZDJSDac021ckV3A3lfloJA9RF6uWtuoQ5bFwgFmngH/ksXSl8kspPadV1RBE5/HoMUGcjSZic4v6FkuVnDdnLXI1lvkcZMlUy3OWzOFbh3GD8chzzpmeA/VDGqWT3W6vSaGAgQD2ncpSOX20iQjxbMqAe7pLkM907EWfZ9NeKOc4jOHrSOjDwePD/Q@Oru/7kgI7lk3tNkKKITzOpg@TMb3ZG8sWxdKyMrbOCOet68U/Ct5QebkWibGEngYBPuC3X5siJciW/p/rGbBDFKtT@LYORfi0XCAuVn@W7mO9fn3GuPr9tHxxyc/V4vll9forvPR0nBlYBeaY7vHW6N1nFo1jKoyAvsoJNSjUzK00nNMTKKirXWqx0MRUehF1BHwSSzzQZUdq0R9lmOG2b@7CvzZEV4PL9T8)