# 3D Hide & Seek Word Puzzle - Seeker edition

Tags: code-golf, word-search

Your [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge is to find all occurences of a word in the 3d matrix. There is no restriction on I/O format. In the samples below, the word is presented, then a blank line, then the 2-dimensional layers from top to bottom, and the output, for each line, consists of a coordinate and a direction (x, then y, then z, where + is positive direction, - is negative direction, and 0 is no change). However, you may choose any other format, for instance a 3D Array, list of list of lists, pre-existing values on tape/stack, etc. Similarly, you may output the coordinate  after the direction, etc. However, the format must be bijectional (always output `1` is not a valid output format) and consistent.

Sample Input

```
CODEGOLF

N Y R Z O F K G   Y G B V E T P M   O J F K Y O O K   O Z N Q F A R P   M X E T N O I Y   F H C U O F Z A   G V A V O O F B   B V K U O V L F    
W Y L W U H H K   Z M Z X D R K Q   G D D A B I D F   P Y G U I D L I   J Y D O M D Q W   F H B Q Q N B B   T A C F J Q L K   H R Y R Y B Z Q    
L F C D Z B Z W   L E A J O F F J   Z O X Q G A R C   W N N W Y Z S U   S G E V T A C F   K F E O R O N V   K D G Z N W O P   L I W W J L C U    
K L Z Q M A G C   M R Q E F M O I   O K T K T U A U   S E X A Y K C D   N J D V G E S G   X O F P T S F I   H Z B X E X U T   X R Q G V P Q O    
B H F C J P Y A   P I Z G R X N A   A W Z H A Z H V   Q X T E T B Z A   Q A V I Z H G D   E H N J L G G W   V K A O Q U S G   N K M M X R G Z    
B Q K R Y O R I   O J C Q K C P F   F U D R M U J G   E K B F A A C I   K G P O B M N E   M P M B K X X T   V B V N Z O R P   K N Q N J B M D
M L R C O U C F   A O H U H R E P   M L E T B F R Y   W J S U C Y A N   M X S W E C C X   C U F U V Q U H   J C Z W Y E J S   Z D C U I R F Z    
C H D I M M C W   F W G N I I Z U   C X W Q M C O N   Y O W K X E Z J   U G Y U W Q V V   C N B T A T E Z   W C X Z E O W Z   N S C J P V X X
```

Sample Output

```
0 0 7 ++-
```

Sample Input

```
AA

A A
A A
```

Sample Output

```
0 0 0 +00
0 0 0 0+0
0 0 0 ++0
1 0 0 -00
1 0 0 0+0
1 0 0 -+0
0 1 0 +00
0 1 0 0-0
0 1 0 +-0
1 1 0 -00
1 1 0 0-0
1 1 0 --0
```

Sample Input

```
SNY

Y X  N X  S X
```

Sample Output

```
0 0 0 00+
```

Sample Input

```
SNY

Y  N  S
```

Sample Output

```
0 0 0 00+
```

Comment: *Inspired by [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269752/3d-hide-seek-word-puzzle#comment585369_269752)*

Comment: Great challenge! Could you elaborate on the direction notation (e.g. `++-`)? What does it mean?

Comment: Done@%#&R^*&T1%&*!(!%#&^*&(

Comment: Can we assume the size of the matrix is the same as the length of the word? If not you should probably add another testcase

Comment: I think the sample cases are enough, but yah i'll add one

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
œẹⱮŒp_ƝỊjEƊẠƊƇQƑƇ
```

A dyadic Link that accepts a multidimensional<sup>*</sup> array of characters (the Board) on the left, and a list of characters (the Word) on the right and yields a list of lists of 1-indexed coordinates.

<sup>* Of any dimension!</sup>

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZO5bttQEEV7fsUU@RHuoiiSohZuTao0hou06Qw3BtTFaVLEQIAUaYwACVLEdhlY/yH9iHLmSggI8j3ed2fmzvKu3l1ffzidXj8dnp@OP3@83r9/u384vOyu0v3u8Px1v9vftfuP@7vT4eU3pKdvx9vH480XMzvePBz@/MreOHD7@Pf76/3h6fPpVNtoK5usscxKyyGOfCPrLLWNLa0CaWyu05Fdw@rIZLW1oCHWS5DKBlnUnBUwjbOZxbaV5wme4bdj7eQlI4YpTilOZwvLgh7LhfUgMx6PNOF5wndCnJKI7iXhCbEtWDOQpTRv9b/ga@gd2TfYJtj0FzUR@xaFkWJv8BGDz8EWijUjxqg3ImYboAhGwt7/3cuCHEMsXL9bmio34CFXJWKQngi1eSaTrVFlfHPsuv8RjWgZSINFA7cTksCaZNmoop5JzzNnRx2DkhVV5BTCjFXzFf8pvipV3dSdjd4trHPsFH0hakrlYkSYs3bStFbHB@WzxGrNWqgSnvMg2y24c1bKsoPXWhNEcLw6c1U/VBcKrHJ4AzEcCVE/wQv19Sxbzjaak@gyE60mohAjl76UXa2scx6vus9IiMYWLWfFNUilmVt51QLvbKnOeU2Ly8zGQmOUZZqAraaoYp3LS8pppBn2vhTqQg67Aa2IkarGfgciTgZpdzU@tbU6f579UnfBNbtdElRo91loiHTut6ufaapXeD3fl8WlDpl0mzq9loXXs77cqTV4ChazN90nz6NTLWaa9FizOcJye5/IRLwCv9y8IIaX8Of1ii93oSfPGszrvpXfAawVo1Fsr2SvrFM4PulbbEa@zuvUzVh3yad6I5bn4J4mzXYvpEbTeUo6r@CpSdJ/)** ("CODEGOLF" will take too long, and "ODE" is there twice, so I used the latter instead.)

#### How?

```
œẹⱮŒp_ƝỊjEƊẠƊƇQƑƇ - Main Link: multidimensional array, Board; list, Word
  Ɱ               - map across {C in Word} with:
œẹ                -   get all coordinates of {C} in {Board}
   Œp             - Cartesian product
                     -> all possible coordinate lists spelling {Word}
             Ƈ    - keep if:
            Ɗ     -   last three links as a monad - f(Coordinates):
      Ɲ           -     for neighbouring pairs:
     _            -       subtract
          Ɗ       -     last three links as a monad - f(Deltas=that):
       Ị          -       {Deltas} insignificant? (vectorises) -> is 0 or 1?
         E        -       {Deltas} all equal?
        j         -       {is 0 or 1(Deltas)} join {all Deltas are equal}
           Ạ      -     all?
              QƑƇ - keep if all distinct -> remove any with repeated coordinates
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 88 bytes

```
ＵＭη⊞Ｏ⁺ιψ ⊞η ＦＬηＦＬ§ηιＦＬ§§ηικＦ³Ｆ³Ｆ³¿∨⊖μ∨⊖ν⊖ξ¿⬤θ⁼π§§§η⁺ι×ρ⊖μ⁺κ×ρ⊖ν⁺λ×ρ⊖ξ⟦⪫⟦ικλ⭆⟦μνξ⟧§-0+π⟧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJNb9s4FLznVwi5WEJVYIEec6IokpIokiIlih@GD0biNkZtOXWcIv31XpHK7qZd5KTh07yZ4eO7f9ye70/bw/XKtk/wdDxup4f0MU@6l@dH8bQ7by@nc9odXp7TfZ78yvLkNrnNsrub8D/wwvHu5uvpnKTtbvp2mYtZlrw/g0s9PexeA3mfffDvN06efP@X9@X/3/3XJBXntNzdn3fH3XTZPaTHueeP0jSX3p9fs6AZesHhkP7IE/TjZXt4Tp/y5M8Q78L8c/Fhf9w9p@ffJY9B8o3z/QPO9I5z@IATo4V03Xk/XdJ1c9pP6Xp2nUXnnv4yl7/Nr5Ouj3ky5cnr5r/Mt5//@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@IYl1LXCb3eAVVkzBpfdMITXtY@zh9ZIBkVUdcJQi3zcAE2cNnKM04O8GMCAfEwBrUfCRMz7efCjtavNZnP9/PPwNw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＵＭη⊞Ｏ⁺ιψ ⊞η
```

Add padding bytes in each dimension. (If I was using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO then I would use `ψ` consistently but unfortunately the version of Charcoal on TIO has what I would call a bug when indexing an array containing `ψ` so I use spaces instead.)

```
ＦＬηＦＬ§ηιＦＬ§§ηικ
```

Loop through every possible starting position (including the padding, but that will get filtered out later anyway).

```
Ｆ³Ｆ³Ｆ³¿∨⊖μ∨⊖ν⊖ξ
```

Loop through every possible direction except no direction (fixes the `AA` test case).

```
¿⬤θ⁼π§§§η⁺ι×ρ⊖μ⁺κ×ρ⊖ν⁺λ×ρ⊖ξ
```

If each character of the array starting at that position and working in that direction equals the target string, then...

```
⟦⪫⟦ικλ⭆⟦μνξ⟧§-0+π⟧
```

... output the position and direction in a readable form.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 345 bytes

```py
from itertools import*
D=[0,1,-1]
E=enumerate
def f(w,b):
 d={}
 for z,Z in E(b):
  for x,X in E(Z):
   for y,v in E(X):d[v]=d.get(v,[])+[(x,y,z)]
 q=[(w[1:],*i,*j,[i])for i in d[w[0]]for j in product(*[D,D,D])if any(j)]
 while q:
  w,x,y,z,X,Y,Z,p=q.pop(0)
  if''==w:yield p;continue
  if(T:=(x+X,y+Y,z+Z))in d[w[0]]:q+=[(w[1:],*T,X,Y,Z,p+[T])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXbcqNGEH0OX9HlF4E0cVn2PqSU0gNC9wsIXRCXUKm1hbK4bIERtixv7bc7pxutdzcvESUYzpzuPt3TM@Sn8ku2v/kjL97fd0X2SGmZFGWWPRwofcyzoqxr3XZ0pZrq92as9drJ/vkxKT6XibZNdrTTj@rWaGm0bX/9ptEuK@hNhZTuqacLLtCr8isoFEiwk3qpMN9obaOXuL29/Ccp9RcVxUYj0l/VSb0ZsUZP7Ug/Rs1WrOqpqt@rKI0Ntk/Zehsdo6s45vd7fs@LbPt8V@r1qKtwxUa6o8/7k37Pno5f0oeEnljBUYl/5atAhSpvP13mWa5fGZhKd7Vau31sndLkYUv5n3fZvkz3z4lM6atWW39t@OrUCNRbIzSMHyJaT40fUlffXTeiVWzE71UpqUi0Q5PadHFxoZlk8p9I47fD9Rm2KaAFheRQnyY0QLUC3DvkUY9WNKcZEIfGMhtg5ODJSEg2uUBNWM@BzMgXCxtzIzAJc0OyaC2eQw4Mvx6ennjpIwZJnIlwPJoCw0/bwHpKG6BDXBwthPcQ/ruINUFU9tTFZcJ@hCfbzUX3Wt6nuBM0Bxg7sO3CZnNW1MHYhcqOxF/BhwV8DGwqsYaIEci/g5iuKGJlFryEgrGnKXI1YcV5sDVJBX3wB1IRC8gGUWzibEJaQhnhPoCd9xGVELEPxIGFA64nSBesUCwdqSxns8E1xsgSP6RNMGZ1M3gaSLQZfLjw1cfIkfx5pVbyX4NVxe9BowlFE8mHEGWMpye6lrL6vuQ0h9USz5FUhPP2xXYNnDkLydQDzwWfFXXA4yqNZSVMWZERLAfg@ojDiIksQvBMuXO2LuZW0jedc4@40iEjYQxEYw8jW7If4OLqc8@YiOtCT6XaBjKTHlxI9SpFLtCFdO3iXJExFLqS/Vzq34cH7qoZnmPx1MNsR/qa12gkKzIA2wE6Q5ye1Jr3RQczvuhnRdzJtnRBtR8msj9YN9t1tRn0c184iFStPWcwlC5fwGu1h6bnWvRFN8mqL8WCa2qf99kSeA@YhTFJT3AentRjKJ1vSZ8GYLE9d2dXeCP47Z/rY4HbBcJ1s877Y4NcbWBc/7X49oG5wnAkPldzI5n3wOHOX8MmwJ15nqyqJfuLu3wlLM6DPYXS6xtBbOiqusWTKtL3g@nmfDAFDNp8W5JfTX36mGIpSwH5q1Bmf99lWbE96Acc@L8VSflc7KPo9vKQP6SlbsgH4JYP7PuYPg7vtzTHwV0kZ1btr8PXa/WtptKKLwf@Ln3A50m3s32i6PDB3NcMA8espuVFui/1qL7Ta6ZZUz8JaTLj53nL6fYGzrT/C@v6v6ylHfxCuPk/wicmvP8L)